# Automatic Database failover and restore

Tags: architecture, failover, redundancy

We have an isolated Java application deployed on two processors primarily for failover in case the primary processor goes down. Let's call them processor A and B. The architecture currently has a set of processes running on A and an Oracle database running on both A and B with streams configured to keep them in sync. In the event that A goes down, processes are started on B to take over and use the database on B.

Then when A comes back up we want the system as a whole to automatically restore to a state where the processes are running on A and the database moves back into an A being primary and B a slave for failover. We mostly have this working where we have defined our own logic to stop the database on B, essentially wipe the database on A and restore it from B then reestablish streams. However, although this works for us 99% of the time we still find synchronization bugs here and there.

It seems to me that we're reinventing the wheel here though, but are we? I feel like there should be a standard method for database clustering where database nodes can come and go where it works out the syncronization for us? Am I being naive or does this already exist, and what buzzwords describe this kind of architecture? Is this what a 'multi master' is? Does a multi-master auto synchronize when one or the other goes down for a period of time?